# Review spam detection using SVM

Tags: python, svm, spam-prevention, sentiment-analysis, review

I have a dataset of reviews from various e-commerce sites.

My task is to classify them into spam or not using SVM in Python.

How should I convert text dataset into SVM features? Are there other features need to be consider and if so, how to convert them into SVM feature vectors?

Is there any sample code or tutorial available to do this task? I need to implement this task, so please guide me on this.

Comment: I would begin by googling "svm for text classification".

Comment: What features would you imagine are useful for classifying these messages into spam vs non-spam?

Comment: If sentiment analysis is what you want to perform, then the output of your sentiment analysis system ought to be a prominent feature.

Comment: tripleee, thanks.but that is what i want to know which features are useful and how to convert them into SVM vectors?

Comment: Then this is definitely too broad.  Yours seems to be a "wag the dog" question -- a special case of ["I want to solve problem X, how do I do Y"](http://xyproblem.info/) where X is an open research problem.

Answer (score 2):

A classic way of converting text input to input you can provide to a machine learning algorithm like SVM:

- Divide your text into a list of tokens (for instance each word, each group of 2 words, etc.)
- Represent the number of occurrences of your tokens according to a given model. For instance TFIDF is a model that weighs each token according to it's frequency into the whole corpus of documents.

Each document is therefore represented by a vector where each component is one word of your corpus of texts vocabulary, and the associated weigh represents a statistical indicator about this word relatively to the document considered.

See scikit-learn http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction for more information about it, and an implementation of the most classic methods for representing a text as a valid input for machine learning algorithms.

Comment: Do i need to manally label my dataset into spam or non spam for SVM?

Comment: Yes you have to, otherwise you won't be able to learn anything with supervised methods like SVM.